# How can I FTP into an ESX Datastore?

Tags: ftp, vmware-esx

I'd like to setup FTP access to my ESX datastore but am not sure what I need to do to get this setup.

Comment: What version and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[THIS](http://www.vm-help.com/esx/esx3i/ESXi_enable_FTP.php) guy appears to have done it but I think it's a bad idea all around, there's probably a supported way of doing whatever it is you're trying to achieve and this might break with patches/updates etc.

Comment: Thanks for this. I will take a closer look at alternative ways to complete the work I'd like to as well. Thanks.